# Размер subwindows окна в mdiArea

Tags: python, pyqt5

У меня при добавлении окна в mdiArea, оно становиться маленьким. Как сделать что бы окно при открытии становилось того размера, который задан в дизайнере?

Скрин дизайнера:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скрин окна в программе.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код примера.

```
main_class, main_base_class = loadUiType(getcwd() + '/ui/main.ui')
class MainWindow(QMainWindow, main_class):
    def __init__(self, *args):
       self.user = my_class.User
       super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args)
       self.setupUi(self)
       self.show()
       self.setDisabled(True)
       self.login = login_window.LoginWindow(self, self.user)
       self.login.show()

    def set_privilege(self):
       if self.user.privilege == "швея":
           self.ma_material.setDisabled(True)
           self.ma_material_provider.setDisabled(True)

    def view_material(self):
       self.material = material.Material()
       self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.material)
       self.material.show()


material_class, material_base_class = loadUiType(getcwd() + '/ui/material.ui')
class Material(QMainWindow, material_class):
   def __init__(self, *args):
       super(Material, self).__init__()
       self.setupUi(self)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = form.main_window.MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение, распишу как могу

```
self.material = material.Material()  # Создаем экземпляр класса окна которое будет внутри MDI
self.sub_material = QMdiSubWindow()  # Создаем пустое под окно MDI
self.sub_material.setWidget(self.material)  # Заполняем пустое окно нашим классом
self.mdi.addSubWindow(self.sub_material)  # Добавляем окно к самой MDI области
self.sub_material.resize(self.material.size())  # Редактируем размер MDI под окна, взяв размеры из созданного в дизайнере класса
self.sub_material.show()  # Отображаем под-окно
```